# Validate object instance type against gereric 'T' type

Tags: java

I have a Class with generic type:

```
class Foo<T> {
    protected boolean validateType(Object obj){
        if (obj instanceof T) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

To test:

```
Foo foo = new Foo<String>();
foo.validateType(new String()); // should return true
foo.validateType(new Long()); // should return false;
```

And have a function that needs to validate an object against the generic type 'T', obviously the code above have errors?

How can I do such

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible at it stands - generics are implemented in Java by [erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), which means that the generic parameter does not exist at runtime.  It's there for the compiler to typecheck, but at runtime there's no way to tell the difference between a `Foo<String>` and a `Foo<Long>`.

So if you want a specific token to check against, you'll have to do this yourself.  A common pattern to do this sort of checking is to use `Class` object, with the benefit that these can be type-checked by the compiler:

```
class Foo<T> {
    private final Class<T> genericClass;

    public Foo(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.genericClass = clazz;
    }

    protected boolean validateType(Object obj){
        return genericClass.isInstance(obj);
    }
}
```

Note that your callers now need to pass in the `Class` object themselves; there's no way around this requirement, it can't be automatically wired in by Java itself.

(Also, it's a bad idea to use `if (x) return true; else return false;` when it's exactly the same as `return x;` but more confusing and error prone.)

Answer (score 1):

So Instance of `Foo` has no information as to what `T` is at runtime. 

So, you have to pass a `Class<T>` to constructor of `Foo`.

```
private final Class<T> cl;

protected boolean validateType(Object ob){
    return cl.isInstance(ob);
}
...
```